# Angular browser debugging info

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, google-chrome

I'm using Angular 6 and my problem is that anyone can see my api calls informations like Authorization in their browser debug window.. I've tryied to enable production deployment but this apprean anyway..
Thank you!

Comment: Don't let anyone watch over your shoulder and make sure you have locked your machine with a password or something similar. This is how it works. The token you're probably referring to is intended to identify the logged in user and it's the users responsibillity to prevent someone else from hijacking it. This is also the reason why tokens should be short in lifetime.

Comment: This is perfectly normal. A user can only see their own login information that they provided. They should only be receiving back data for their own account. What is the problem?

Comment: Yes but I use paypal client and secret id to do some calls to paypal API's

Comment: You shouldn't be using clientId + secret in the browser. Delegate that to your server.